# How do I get CFNetwork operations to stop trusting a certificate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have set up my App to allow switching SSL certificate validation on and off based on the URL using the mechansim outlined here:
[Objective-C/Cocoa: How do I accept a bad server certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266/objective-c-cocoa-how-do-i-accept-a-bad-server-certificate)

this basically sets the client to accept a 'bad' certificate from the server. My problem is that subsequent calls to the same server all complete correctly, even if I set it to have strict certificate checking.

I assume that the underlying CFNetwork implementation is caching the certificate and its 'trusted' status. I don't want this behaviour.

Is there any way to either turn off certificate caching in general/for a specific request, or at least to purge the cache

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OS X [Keychain Access utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_Access) to examine your login keychain.  You can delete or change the trust policy of cached certificates from there.  There is also a command-line interface: `/usr/bin/security`.

Comment: Thanks Ned, I am really looking for a programmatic interface though. I won't actually be notified of the certificate that gets passed. I have just set the read stream to not validate certificates.