# Applying SSL On Web Server

Tags: android, ios, iphone, web-services, ssl

I have a web service for my android and Iphone application that connects to online database.
now we want to apply SSL on the web server. will this effect on my web service?

will the android and iphone applications keeps running or will be stopped? because in the applications they are linked to the web service like this

```
http://www.example.com/service/index.php
```

and now after applying SSL the website will be like

```
https://www.example.com
```

should I change my applications to

```
https://www.example.com/service/index.php
```

or its ok if I kept the old link in my applications (android and iphone)?

Comment: They won't work unless http mode is still active

Comment: @kike can you give me more information about http mode. because I'm a developer and this is the first time that I'm going to apply SSL on the server.

Comment: I mean that if you have both modes, http and https it will work, if http redirects to https it won't. 
Check your webservice URL with http//www... and if it works (without redirecting to https), they will work.

Comment: I took time to prepare an answer because I think it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we enable SSL in our server we can keep our unsecure http access or redirect it to secure https.

Use secure communication is always a good practice but it will cost you a bit more of effort.

As an Android developer I was able to use https REST webservices thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) answer.

For iOS I have no idea but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663768/https-ios-with-self-signed-certificate) answer could be a good starting point.